# Add class to an element, only when another class is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this question could have similar duplicates but I can't find the solution. I have a slider with 3 slides. The plugin is the [lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/). What I want to achieve is to fire a css animation to an element every time the 3rd slider is the current. I noticed that a class of `active` is being added to the current slide then, the this slide is the current-visible, like in the screenshot below.

[image]

So my initial thought was the following. Grab the specific element ie `svg-slide`, check if the element has a class of `active`, and if yes, add the css class that fires the animation.

My code for that:

```
if ( $('.svg-slide').hasClass('active') ) {
   $('.svg-slide').addClass('fire-animation');
}
```

The problem with this one is, and correct me if I'm wrong, that when the page loads, the class of `active` is on the 1st slide, so the code has already checked that `svg-slide` doesn't have the `active` class and it does nothing afterwards. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The moment I was saving the edit your wrote the comment. Thanks anyways. ;). My code didn't have the syntax error btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `getCurrentSlideCount` method with `onAfterSlide` event? And on change of the slide, if the current slide is the third slide you add the class you want:

```js
var yourSlider = $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
  loop:true,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  onAfterSlide: function (el) {
    var currentSlide = el.getCurrentSlideCount();
    if(currentSlide == 3){
       //add your class
      $('.active').addClass('TESTING');
    } else {
      $('.active').removeClass('TESTING');
    }
  } 
});
```

I've also made you a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/015Lcjt0/6/).

Comment: +1 for providing code related to the plugin! So, right now if I put a simple `console.log` there, it works. I can see it in the console every time the 3rd slide is the current. But when I do this `$('.a-class').addClass('animation-class')`, I can't see the class in the DOM neither the animations fires.

Comment: @appostolis, I changed the code a bit. Use onAfterSlide instead onBeforeSlide. I've also made you a fiddle. Check my answer. Now it's adding the class.

Comment: thanks! I got it working with `onAfterSlide` too! The problem though is that even if I use `toggleClass` it doesn't work every time the slide is current. Only once. Thanks for the help btw. I'm accepting this as the answer.

Comment: aaand got it working with adding an `else` statement. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.